# Prove that the chord always passes through a fixed point

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

If the end points $P(t_1)$ and $Q(t_2)$ of a chord of a parabola $y^2=4ax$ satisfy the relation $t_1t_2=k$(constant) then prove that the chord always passes through a fixed point.Find that point also.

---

Let $P(at^2_1,2at_1)$ and $Q(at^2_2,2at_2)$,then the equation of the line joining P and Q is $y(t_1+t_2)-2x-2at_2=0$
But i am stuck here.Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the parameters be $p,q$ (instead of $t_1, t_2$) hence points are $P(ap^2, 2ap), Q(aq^2, 2aq)$.

Equation of chord PQ:

$$\begin{align}
\frac {y-2ap}{2aq-2ap}&=\frac {x-ap^2}{aq^2-ap^2}\\
\frac {y-2ap}{2(q-p)}&=\frac {x-ap^2}{(q-p)(q+p)}
&&(q\neq p)\\
(p+q)y&=2(x+apq)\\
(p+q)y&=2(x+ka)\end{align}$$
which always passes through $(-ka, 0)$.

---

It is interesting to note  the following:

- when $k=-1$, the chord always passes through the focus, $(a,0)$,
- when $k=1$, the chord always intersects the $x-$axis at the directrix, i.e. at $(-a,0)$.